# Scrape eBay Product Description

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium + Java to scrape EBay product descriptions. Currently, the easiest way to get the description is by using XPath: `.//*[@id='ds_div']`. However this scrapes everything—including sellers template images, shipping information and details directly related to the seller's policy—which I don't want or need.

I need to scrape only the details of product itself (such as features and product description) without any extraneous details.

The problem is there is no single XPath/CSS I can use to get this—as the XPath/CSS varies from seller to seller.

What is the best approach to obtain this information?

Thanks

Comment: The best way to get the information is to use their API instead.